# Can´t find "window" function in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I´m coding a small example in `Spark Structured Streaming` where I´m trying to process the output of the `netstat`command and can´t figure out how to invoke the `window`function.

These are the relevant lines of my build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"

libraryDependencies ++= {

  val sparkVer = "2.3.0"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVer % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % sparkVer % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % "provided" withSources(),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVer % "provided",
  )
}
```

And the code:

```
case class NetEntry(val timeStamp: java.sql.Timestamp, val sourceHost: String, val targetHost: String, val status: String)

def convertToNetEntry(x: String): NetEntry = {
    // tcp        0      0 eselivpi14:icl-twobase1 eselivpi149.int.e:48442 TIME_WAIT
   val array = x.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").split(" ").slice(3,6)
   NetEntry(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()), array(0),array(1),array(2))
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Initialize spark context
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val lines = spark.readStream
    .format("socket")
    .option("host", args(0))
    .option("port", args(1).toInt)
    .load()

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = lines.as[String].map(x => convertToNetEntry(x))

    val wordsArr: Dataset[NetEntry] = df.as[NetEntry]
    wordsArr.printSchema()

    // Never get past this point
    val windowColumn = window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes")

    val windowedCounts = wordsArr.groupBy( windowColumn, $"targetHost").count()

    val query = windowedCounts.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
    query.awaitTermination()
}
```

I have with Spark 2.1, 2,2 and 2.3 with the same results. What is really bizarre is that, I have a Spark Cluster, I log in the Spark Shell and copy all the lines... and it works! Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

The error at compilation time:

```
[error] C:\code_legacy\edos-dp-mediation-spark-consumer\src\main\scala\com\ericsson\streaming\structured\StructuredStreamingMain.scala:39: not found: value window
[error]     val windowColumn = window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes")
[error]                        ^
[warn] 5 warnings found
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 19 s, completed 16-mar-2018 20:13:40
```

*Update*: To make things weirder, I have check the API docs and I could not found a valid reference here either:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import the `window` function to compile it, which is already imported in spark-shell.

Add this import statement:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window
```

Comment: That solved my problem! However this is nowhere to be found in the documentation, and we are talking about a "Hello World" example here...

Comment: From which source are you following this example? The Structured Streaming Programming Guide here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html  does have this import statement which loads all the sql functions: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`